# Не могу понять почему ответы не сохраняются в файле. Надо ввести имя пользователя неоднократное кол-во раз

Tags: python, while

```
with open('guest_book', 'w') as file_object:
    while True:
        name = input('')
        if  name == 1:
            break
        file_object.write(name)
```

Comment: а как вы выходите из цикла ? (ваше условие с `break` никогда не сработает)

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что цикл ввода вы завершаете сами нажатимем `Ctrl-C` (ваше условие с `break` не сработает, потому что при сравнение строки и числа ответ всегда `False`). Из-за этого всё, что вы ввели не записывается в файл (особенность работы буфера записи в файл).
Чтобы исправить эту ошибку достаточно сравнивать ввод со строкой, при которой нужно завершить цикл ввода.

```
with open('guest_book', 'w') as file_object:
    while True:
        name = input('')
        if  name == '1': # <---
            break
        file_object.write(name)
```

Однако так все "имена", введенные пользователем, будут записаны в одну строку и без разделителя. Так добавим же разделитель

```
file_object.write(name + '\n')
```

---

Ну и добавлю "современный" код

```
with open('guest_book', 'w') as file_object:
    while (name:=input('')) != '1':
        file_object.write(name + '\n')
```